# Monogame android: How to load XNB model from stream or web service?

Tags: c#, android, monogame

I am working on Monogame for Xamarin Android project. 
Anyone know how to load a XNB model which was created from a web service? Basically my web service will return a XNB file and Android device should be able to get that file to display 3D model instantly. I know how to load static XNB model from Assets Content folder but do not know how to load it from stream or external web service, something like this:

```
protected override void LoadContent()
{            
     spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
     myModel = Content.Load<Model>("http://mywebservice.com/getXNBModel/1/");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended up creating new class derived from ContentManager:

```
class XNBContentManager : ContentManager
{
        class FakeGraphicsService : IGraphicsDeviceService
        {   
            public FakeGraphicsService(GraphicsDevice graphicDevice)
            {
                GraphicsDevice = graphicDevice;
            }

            public GraphicsDevice GraphicsDevice { get; private set; }

#pragma warning disable 67
            public event EventHandler<EventArgs> DeviceCreated;
            public event EventHandler<EventArgs> DeviceDisposing;
            public event EventHandler<EventArgs> DeviceReset;
            public event EventHandler<EventArgs> DeviceResetting;
#pragma warning restore 67
        }

        class FakeServiceProvider : IServiceProvider
        {
            GraphicsDevice _graphicDevice;
            public FakeServiceProvider(GraphicsDevice graphicDevice)
            {
                _graphicDevice = graphicDevice;
            }

            public object GetService(Type serviceType)
            {
                if (serviceType == typeof(IGraphicsDeviceService))
                    return new FakeGraphicsService(_graphicDevice);

                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        private readonly MemoryStream _xnbStream;

        public XNBContentManager(MemoryStream xnbStream, GraphicsDevice graphicDevice)
            : base(new FakeServiceProvider(graphicDevice), "Content")
        {
            _xnbStream = xnbStream;
        }

        protected override Stream OpenStream(string assetName)
        {
            return new MemoryStream(_xnbStream.GetBuffer(), false);
        }
 }
```

Then use it in LoadContent method:

```
protected override void LoadContent()
{
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
    var content = new XNBContentManager(_xnbStream, this.GraphicsDevice);
    myModel = content.Load<Model>("WhateverName");
}
```